# How to rename a column heading in a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv

I cannot work out how to rename a column heading in a CSV file with Windows PowerShell. I can add new rows, delete rows, fill, and export, but cannot find out how to change a header value.

I thought I could import the CSV & export with headers specified, but taht doesn't work:

```
import-csv c:\tmp\test.csv | Select-Object first_name | Export-Csv -header "test" c:\tmp\test1.csv
```

I basically need to re-format a CSV file, so if I can select the data I want & specify the new headers that would be perfect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to do this:

```
Import-Csv test.csv |
    Select-Object @{ expression={$_.first_name}; label='test' } |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation test1.csv
```

Answer (score 10):

Can't you try something like this?

```
import-csv 'c:\tmp\test.csv'  | select -Property @{name="test";expression={$($_.first_name)}}| Export-Csv c:\tmp\test1.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method for when you need to change one (or several) columns without the need for hardcoding each column:

```
function Convert-Object($rec){
    $object = New-Object System.Object
    $members = ($rec[0].psobject.Members | ?{$_.MemberType -match "Property"}).Name.Trim()
    foreach($mem in $members){
        if($mem -eq 'File Number'){
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FileNumber" -Value $rec.'File Number'
        }else{
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $mem -Value $rec.$mem
        }
    }
    return $object 
}

$convCSV   = ($CSVs | ?{$_.Name -match "YourCsvName"}).FullName #multiple CSVs perhaps
$toConvert = Import-Csv $convCSV
$convObjs  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$toConvert | foreach{$convObjs += Convert-Object -rec $_}
$convObjs  | Export-Csv $convCSV -NoTypeInformation
```