# Changing CSV report entry if duplicates exist with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, duplicates

I'm pretty new to powershell, so I'll do my best to explain myself. I'm currently working with a script which creates a csv report of access levels for all users and user groups on a server. Breaking it down between Admin and User privileges. As is, it currently out puts two entries for groups which have both Admin and User access. Resembling the following image. (posted as an image due to some trouble with creating a table on stackoverflow)

[image: Current Layout]

I was hoping for some suggestions about how to consolidate users/groups which repeat in the report into one entry with an X in both fields. Kind of like the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1RUa.png]

Here is my current script:

```
 [CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(    ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
                )]
    [string[]]
    $ComputerName = $env:ComputerName,

    [Parameter()]
    [array] $LocalGroupNames = @("Administrators", "Remote Desktop Users"),

    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $LocalGroupName,

    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $OutputDir = "c:\temp"
)

Begin {
    $OutputFile = Join-Path $OutputDir "OSUsers $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
    Add-Content -Path $OutPutFile -Value "ServerName, User\Group, Administrator, User"
    }

Process {
    ForEach($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        foreach ($LocalGroupName in $LocalGroupNames) {
        Write-host "Working on $Computer"
        If(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
            Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,Offline,Offline,Offline"
            Continue
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "Working on $computer"
            try {
                $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$LocalGroupName"
                $members = @($group.Invoke("Members"))
                Write-Verbose "Successfully queries the members of $computer"
                if(!$members) {
                    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,NoMembersFound"
                    Write-Verbose "No members found in the group"
                    continue
                }
            }        
            catch {
                Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,FailedToQuery"
                Continue
            }
            foreach($member in $members) {
                try {
                    $MemberName = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                    $MemberType = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Class","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                    $MemberPath = $member.GetType().Invokemember("ADSPath","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                    $MemberDomain = $null
                    if($MemberPath -match "^Winnt\:\/\/(?<domainName>\S+)\/(?<CompName>\S+)\/") {
                        if($MemberType -eq "User") {
                            $MemberType = "LocalUser"
                        } elseif($MemberType -eq "Group"){
                            $MemberType = "LocalGroup"
                        }
                        $MemberDomain = $matches["CompName"]

                    } elseif($MemberPath -match "^WinNT\:\/\/(?<domainname>\S+)/") {
                        if($MemberType -eq "User") {
                            $MemberType = "DomainUser"
                        } elseif($MemberType -eq "Group"){
                            $MemberType = "DomainGroup"
                        }
                        $MemberDomain = $matches["domainname"]

                    } else {
                        $MemberType = "Unknown"     
                        $MemberDomain = "Unknown"
                    }
                if ($MemberType -ne "Unknown") ##Exclude unresolved users
                {
                    if ($LocalGroupName -eq "Administrators")
                    {Add-Content -Path $OutPutFile -Value "$Computer, $MemberName, X, ,"}
                    if ($LocalGroupName -eq "Remote Desktop Users")
                    {Add-Content -Path $OutPutFile -Value "$Computer, $MemberName, , X,"}
                }
                } catch 
                {
                    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer, ,FailedQueryMember"
                } 
                }

            } 
        }

    }
}
End {}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing anything at all before asking other people to do your work for you?

Comment: I've done quite a bit of  searching for a module or function which would allow me to do this. I was thinking that using "-unique" would work, but I need to be able to add the "X" to the user/group, where unique seems to just be removing repeated users/groups.

Comment: I'm just looking for a suggestion to point me in the right direction. I can do my own work. :)

Comment: Please note, this is my first time posting to stackoverflow and I'm not completely sure how much detail I should be including in a post. I have a functioning script, and this is just a final touch I was hoping to implement. I'm open to suggestions on how to improve the quality of this post, or provide the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you may want to do here is get the members of both the Administrators and Remote Desktop Users, and then with a foreach statement, check the results for each user's presence in both groups or not.

Compare-Object might be your friend here as well, as you can determine how to handle what you write to your file. That command will output "<=", "=>", or "==" if you use the -IncludeEqual parameter.

Ex:

[Powershell - find items which are in array1 but NOT in array2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244522/powershell-find-items-which-are-in-array1-but-not-in-array2)